# Strange Login error causes server to crash - AngularJS / MEAN stack

Tags: javascript, angularjs, mean-stack

I am a newbie programmer in AngularJS and I have a small problem with my login function. It seems that it crashes the server whenever I type in a username that doesn't exist with a random password, but it doesn't crash if the username is registered and I type in a random password. 
It is really annoying and I hope you guys have a few hints for me. 
I will post the code down below.

First things first, here is a screenshot from the server when it crashes -

[image]

server.js - The console points to line 100 in this file, which is the "bcrypt.compare(req.body.password etc etc)", which crashes the server.

```
    app.put('/users/signin', function (req, res, next) {

    db.collection('users', function (err, usersCollection) {

        usersCollection.findOne({username: req.body.username}, function (err, user) {

            bcrypt.compare(req.body.password, user.password, function (err, result) {
                if (result) {
                    var token = jwt.encode(user, JWT_SECRET);
                    return res.json({token: token});
                } else {
                    return res.status(400).send();
                }
            });
        });
    });
});
```

index.html - This is the file I keep my controllers in.

```
$scope.signIn = function () {

                if ($scope.signin.$valid) {
                    $http.put('/users/signin', { username: $scope.username, password: $scope.password })
                    .then(function (res) {
                        $cookies.put('token', res.data.token);
                        $cookies.put('currentUser', $scope.username);
                        $rootScope.token = res.data.token;
                        $rootScope.currentUser = $scope.username;
                    }
                )}
                else {
                    alert('Invalid credentials. Please try again.');
                }

                    };
```

Login HTML code.

```
<div class="panel-body">
                        <br />
                        <form name="signin">
                            <div class="form-group-md">
                                <input type="text" ng-required="true" placeholder="Username" class="form-control" ng-model="username">
                            </div>

                            <br />
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <input type="password" ng-required="true" placeholder="Password" class="form-control" ng-model="password">
                            </div>
                            <br />

                            <button type="button" class="btn btn-success btn-md" ng-click="signIn()">Sign in</button>
                        </form>
                    </div>
```

Did I forget anything? Tell me so! Thanks :)

Comment: `usersCollection.findOne({username: req.body.username}` is returning a null user. `console.log(user)` before the bcrypt call.

Comment: Fixed it with an if-statement. If the user is null, a bad request will be sent and it keeps the server alive.
Seems to be working fine but if you know a better way please share! :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your controller code where you `findOne` from the `userCollection`, check if there's any `err` before proceeding. Do the same for the existence of `user`. Something like this :

```
app.put('/users/signin', function (req, res, next) {
db.collection('users', function (err, usersCollection) {
    usersCollection.findOne({username: req.body.username}, function (err, user) {
        if(err){
            console.log("Error : " + JSON.stringify(err));
        }
        if(!user){
            return res.send(404, "Invalid Username or Password.");
        }
        if(user){
            bcrypt.compare(req.body.password, user.password, function (err, result) {
                if (result) {
                    var token = jwt.encode(user, JWT_SECRET);
                    return res.json({token: token});
                } else {
                    return res.status(400).send();
                }
            });
        }
    });
});
});
```

Comment: Went about the same way yesterday, thanks! Only thing I'm missing is the "Username has not been registered yet" message if I try to log into an account with wrong password :)

Comment: Forgot one thing. It's not advisable to tell in the error message if the username doesn't exist or password is not correct as far as security is concerned So I edited my answer to show the exact error message that should be sent. Hope this helps.

Comment: Yeah I wrote something similar. Thanks again :)